# A Finite Combinatorial Sum

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

It can be proved by induction or telescoping sum that
$$\sum_{i=0}^n {2i\choose i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=(2n+1){2n\choose n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}.$$
However, without knowing the right hand side in advance, I would like to know how one can evaluate the sum on the left hand side, using perhaps generating functions or other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ogf of the left side is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n {2i \choose i} \dfrac{x^n}{2^{2i}}$$
Interchange the order of summation: 
 $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{n = i}^\infty$, and you get

$$ (1-x)^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^\infty {2i \choose i} (x/4)^i = \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{3/2}} $$

Now use the binomial series.

Comment: Thank you! If I replace $\frac{1}{2}$ with a general $p$, is there a nice way to find the coefficient to $x^n$? As a matter of fact, before I posed the question, I tried this very generating function method but with the general $p$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$. I got stuck with a multiplication of two fractions. I tried finding residues in the complex plane but to no avail and gave up.